# OS X PHP server with Crons

Tags: php, macos, cron, osx-server

I have an OS X 10.6 Server running apache, php. I have CronniX installed to help me manage my cron jobs. I have a php script like this:

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
foreach ($a as $v):
echo $v;
?>
```

As you can see the `endforeach;` command is missing, but the cron output (as seen from CronniX Task's tab) does not show any errors, it just dies.

This is not a `foreach / endforeach` vs. `{ }` issue, none work.

Of course error reporting is valuable for me in more complex scripts, where it's impossible to debug without it.

Thanks!

Comment: You do have short_open_tag=On in your php.ini, right?

Comment: Does the script work if you manually run it from the command line? If it doesn't work there, then it's definitely not going to work under cron.

Comment: right :). I think it has something to do with the way the cron runs, because if I access a page in the browser errors do get reported.

Comment: @Marc the output from Terminal's `php /Volumes/[..]` is: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected $end in /Volumes/dev1/cron/cron.php on line 11` so it's as expected;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the fact that it's a **parse error**. In order to be able to catch parse errors you would need to append the php file

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /Volumes/dev1/http/auto-prepend.php
```

and user `register_shutdown_function` in `auto-prepend.php`.